# Why does m<a> = <a>, where <a> is a cyclic group generated by a?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've seen several proofs that seem to use this property, and I do not understand it. For example:

Q: What is the order of the element 14 + <8> in the factor group Z24/<8>?

Solution:

14 + <8> = 6 + <8>

2(6 + <8>) = 12 + <8> = 4 + <8>.

3(6 + <8>) = 18 + <8> = 2 + <8>.

4(6 + <8>) = 24 + <8> = <8>.

This implies that 2<8> = 3<8> = 4<8> = <8>, but why is that true? 
For example, if <8> under Z24 = {8, 16, 1}, then it seems 3<8> = {24, 48, 3} = {1, 1, 3} which is different from {8, 16, 1}.

Can someone please explain what I am missing?

Comment: $(a+<c>) + (b+ <c>)$ is defined to be $(a+b) + <c>$. This sum is well defined because $<c> + <c> = <c>$, where the sum is the sum of all pairs of elements. If that is your definition of $m<c>$ as $<c>+<c>+...+<c>$ with $m$ summands then fine, but don't confuse it with $<mc>$.

Comment: You can show that $<c> + <c> = <c>$. If $r\in <c>$ then there is $k$ such that $a=kc= kc+0c\in <c> + <c>$. On the other hand if $b\in <c> + <c>$ then there are $i, j$ such that $b=ic + jc=(i+j)c\in <c>$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that $\langle 8\rangle$ is not the set $\{8,16,1\}$, but rather $\{0,8,16\}$.

Also, and more to the point, you seem to want to be distributing, where $2(a+\langle 8\rangle) = 2a + 2\langle 8\rangle$, but that's not how coset arithmetic works. Indeed, $(6+\langle 8\rangle)+(6+\langle 8\rangle)= (6+6)+\langle 8\rangle$, *by definition*. Review your definitions of coset arithmetic.